# Relationship between the magnitude of the electric field and distance of a charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I need to understand better the relationship between the magnitude of an electric field of a charge vs the distance from that charge. Does the magnitude of the electric field increases with a shorter distance?

Answer (score 1):

The electric field is given by the following formula:
$$E = \frac{1}{4π} \frac{Q}{r^2}$$

$Q$ is the charge on the particle and $E$ is the electric field produced by that particle.

As $r$ tends to zero, E tends to infinity. Therefore, the magnitude of the electric field will be very high for very small $r$.